# Designing Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, design-patterns

I am writing a Cocoa application that I keep adding buttons, views, and layers to. However, because of all these additions my appdelegate class has become rather big and difficult to read. I therefore decided to move some of the UI related calls to other classes from the appdelegate. However, it seems UI calls have to be done only on the main thread, and (correct me if I am wrong) from the appdelegate. My experiment to move calls into other classes also made me run into difficulties on making sure everything was performed correctly on the main thread. So, all of my UI calls are still called from the appdelegate class.

My questions is how can I improve the design of my application? Can I call the UI from other classes than the appdelegate in a way that avoids problems with threading? Can I split the appdelegate class into severeal files, one for buttons, one for views etc., or is there a better way to design the application? Any suggestions on links to examples or tutorials/books are greatly appreciated.

Thanks everyone. Cheers, Trond

Comment: Since you tagged this with `Cocoa`, I'm assuming you're working on the Mac, right?

Comment: Yes. I should have made it more clear that I am working on the Mac.

Comment: AppKit does not care what you do or do not do from the application object's delegate. The only things that must be in a given object's delegate are the methods of its delegate protocol—and even then, usually only some of them (notification methods can be implemented anywhere). View drawing code should be in a view (never draw into a view from another object). Aside from those, there are no requirements that any given kind of code should be in any particular class.

Comment: And I want to stress my use of the phrase “application object's delegate”, in preference to “app delegate”. There is no such thing as “app delegate” as a crown that confers upon the wearing object some special status above any other objects. The “app delegate” is simply the object that is the delegate of the application object. In almost all applications, the application object's delegate should be the *least* important object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cocoa is based heavily on the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architecture. There is some really great reading on how to use this pattern in Cocoa in the [Cocoa Design Patterns](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html) reference. Basically, you want to have as little UI code in the app delegate as possible. The app delegate should be responsible *only* for app-level control, if possible. It's much better to put UI controller code in separate controller classes. The MVC architecture leads you down the right path; Cocoa provides the views, you write your model classes—the "business" logic of your app—and then use a view controller to coordinate the two.

Answer (score 3):

UI calls need to be done from the main thread, that part is correct. However, you don't need to do them from the app delegate. You can do them everywhere you like, as long as it's done on the main thread.

Now, some UI things *can* be done on other threads but AFAIK UIKit is not designed to be thread-safe and thus strange things and crashes may occur.

There's nothing wrong with splitting things off into other specialized classes. I do it all the time. You might want to introduce a single object that stores and manages states and maybe gives access to your specialized "controllers".

Have a look at `UIViewController` and what it offers you, if you can split your app into "pages" this might be the way to go.

Comment: The question is about Cocoa, not Cocoa Touch. UIKit is not relevant here. Everything you said is true about AppKit, though, up until the last paragraph.

Comment: @Peter Hosey: You're right, my brain somehow smuggled in a "Touch". Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: My non-touch Cocoa is a bit rusty, but replacing "UIViewController" and "pages" with "NSWindowController" and "windows" probably makes even the last paragraph applicable.